# Setting Null Values to a duplicate row and then keeping only 1 row

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I need your help.

My database would be configured to indicate that some of our employees are sharing the same office.

But what happens for instance, when I go to remove the employees from that office space, I'm just setting the LastName and FirstName column values to 'null'. The problem here is that I only want to keep one row value of the same data and not the 2 rows which basically contain the same data.

Maybe perhaps there is a better way of going about this, as I am relatively new to this so i'm open to suggestions from the experts here on this site.

Thanks in advance,

Here is the SQLFiddle in question: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c31e3/1

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_accdb (
    Floor varchar(255),
    Office varchar(255),
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255) 
);

INSERT INTO tbl_accdb (Floor, Office, LastName, FirstName)
VALUES ('2', 'B-47', 'Smith', 'John');

INSERT INTO tbl_accdb (Floor, Office, LastName, FirstName)
VALUES ('2', 'B-47', 'Doe', 'Jane');

UPDATE tbl_accdb
SET
  LastName = null,
  FirstName = null
WHERE Floor = 2 AND Office = 'B-47';
```

Comment: What is the exact logical flow here?  Assuming that floor 2 office B-47 already has one record in your table, what should happen when someone tries to insert a duplicate?

Comment: http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/delete-duplicates-sql-server/.  There are many other sites that show how to delete duplicate rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is to upgrade your database. SQL Server 2008 is out of extended support since earlier this year, which means you wont even get security updates from Microsoft your your server. It's high time to upgrade.

Having said that, now let's deal with the table structure itself.

The first thing I would do here is to separate your data into two tables - One to contain office information, and one to contain employee data.

In the employee table I would add a column that is a foreign key to the office table, which will indicate which employee works in which office - since there can be many employees in a single office, but an employee can only have one main office they work in.

```
CREATE TABLE tblOffice (
    Id int identity(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_Office PRIMARY KEY,
    Floor int, -- Since this is a number, store it as a number.
    Office varchar(255), -- Do you really need all that length?
    -- Other office related data such as capacity etc'
    CONSTRAINT UX_Office UNIQUE (Floor, Office) 
);

CREATE TABLE tblEmployee (
    EmployeeNumber int CONSTRAINT PK_Employee PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    -- Other employee related data such as social security number etc'
    OfficeId int CONSTRAINT FK_Employee_Office REFERENCES TblOffice(Id)
);
```